# Android dynamically drawing more than 1000 text view is causing full application to not responding

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-contentprovider

This is my function which will fetch some 1300 record from SQLite database and draw a series of text view inside the table layout. But when  this function starts executing full application is not responding for some time. Table layout is again inside a Scroll View.

Basically I want it to load in back ground.so that remaining application is still responsive

```
   public void LoadAlarmNotifications() {

     int SerNo = 0 ;
     TextView SerNoTxtVw;
     TextView AlarmTxtVw;
     TextView TimeOccuredTxtVw;  
     TextView UploadTxtTxtVw;  
     Notificationtablelayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

     pastEvent_tbleList  = oDatabaseHandler.FetchPastEventDetails(sDiagnosisID);

     if(pastEvent_tbleList != null)
       {
            for(Pastevents_tble PEvents_tble: pastEvent_tbleList)
            {
                     final TableRow row = new TableRow(this.getApplicationContext());
                     nAlarmType          = PEvents_tble.GetAlarmID();
                     nRowID              = PEvents_tble.GetEventNo(); 
                     SerNo               = PEvents_tble.GetEventNo();
                     SetAlarmType(nAlarmType);  // Set Alarm
                     tAlarmTime          = PEvents_tble.GetStrtTime(); 
                     sUploadStatus       = PEvents_tble.GetUploadStatus();
                     row.setId(nRowID);

                     SerNoTxtVw      =new TextView(this.getApplicationContext());
                     AlarmTxtVw      =new TextView(this.getApplicationContext());
                     TimeOccuredTxtVw=new TextView(this.getApplicationContext());
                     UploadTxtTxtVw  =new TextView(this.getApplicationContext()); 

                     SerNoTxtVw.setText(Integer.toString(SerNo));
                     SerNoTxtVw.setWidth(80);
                     SerNoTxtVw.setHeight(40);
                     SerNoTxtVw.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                     SerNoTxtVw.setPadding(2, 2,2,2);
                     SerNoTxtVw.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFAADDFF"));
                     row.addView(SerNoTxtVw);

                     AlarmTxtVw.setText(sAlarmName);
                     AlarmTxtVw.setWidth(100);
                     AlarmTxtVw.setHeight(40);
                     AlarmTxtVw.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                     AlarmTxtVw.setPadding(2,2,2,2);
                    // AlarmTxtVw.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                     row.addView(AlarmTxtVw);

                     TimeOccuredTxtVw.setText(tAlarmTime);
                     TimeOccuredTxtVw.setWidth(140);
                     TimeOccuredTxtVw.setHeight(40);
                     TimeOccuredTxtVw.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                     TimeOccuredTxtVw.setPadding(2,2,2,2);
                    // TimeOccuredTxtVw.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                     row.addView(TimeOccuredTxtVw);

                     UploadTxtTxtVw.setText(sUploadStatus);
                     if(sUploadStatus.equals("Y")){
                         UploadTxtTxtVw.setText("✔");
                         UploadTxtTxtVw.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF00FF00")); 
                     }
                     else if(sUploadStatus.equals("N")){
                         UploadTxtTxtVw.setText("X");
                         UploadTxtTxtVw.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFF0000")); 
                      }else
                      {
                         UploadTxtTxtVw.setText("✔");
                         UploadTxtTxtVw.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFAADDFF"));
                      }

                     UploadTxtTxtVw.setWidth(100);
                     UploadTxtTxtVw.setHeight(40);
                     UploadTxtTxtVw.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                     UploadTxtTxtVw.setPadding(2,2,2,2);
                    // UploadTxtTxtVw.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                     row.addView(UploadTxtTxtVw);

                     Notificationtablelayout.addView(row); 


                     nProgressCounter++;

                     row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                    public void onClick(final View SelectedRowVw) {  
                          if(!bSwitchPopOpen)
                          {

                          }

                    });
            }  

            LoadingTxtView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            bEpisodeLoad = true;
       } else
       {
            bEpisodeLoad = true;
            LoadingTxtView.setText("No Snapshot available...");

       } 
}
```

pastEvent_tbleList size is 1335. Any idea how to optimize this. Instead of text view is there any other light control?

Comment: Go ahead with async task,Load your data using async task and once data is loaded update the view, you can find many samples over net

Comment: relating to the post title...it's not android rendering 1000+ textview, it's rather YOU crashing the app...how about some paging implementation?

Comment: why not you are using listview with customlist adapter class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [Loader](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) pattern to do this so that you only load content that the user will actually see, and you should also reuse the text views on the screen. This is what [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) / [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) were created to solve, so you really ought to reuse these components if at all possible.

Comment: Any example on this will be much helpfull

Comment: Do I need to put list view inside, scroll View?

Comment: No, you do not need to put it in a ScrollView.

Comment: it will automatically scroll, if item goes out side of visible area?

Comment: The ListView automatically scrolls in the direction that you specify (it won't scroll in the other direction, and if you need it to scroll in both directions, you should probably redesign your UI).

Comment: perfect solution  list is good control ..it worked for 2000 item also..cheers

Answer (score 1):

You should use listview, because it loads visible area so application will not stop doing calculations and you can scroll up and down and see your texviews